# OpenVPN maintain connection state during tunnel reconnect

Tags: networking, iptables, routing, openvpn

Sometimes I want to do a short maintenance like restarting a tunnel, all connection running on top such as file transfer...etc will receive connection lost signal, is it possible to maintain those connection state so that when I flip the tunnel it doesn't drop all existing connection?

I should ask, is it possible to tell OpenVPN to hold existing connection for a period of time until tunnel resume?